# Including a decimal in a string not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet I get from someone in Europe, so the number formats are funky:

```
18890.00
18 644
19 264
19 318
19 113,6
7 407,75
17 988,75
14 456
19.168
18 922
19 504,5
18 310,29375
```

(a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSCA2.jpg), just for your visual delight)

Note: that's in column "H" (so it's all one column, multiple rows).  You *cannot* add these as numbers, or use math (doing `=Sum(H1:H2)` returns a `#VALUE` error).  The first number is formatted like I need - however, all the ones after that aren't.  You'll notice there's a space in them, the decimal marker is a comma, and the thousands separator is a decimal.  (I'm aware that this is standard EUR format). Using "text to columns" and choosing "Text" data format, then "Advanced" and telling it the decimal separator is a space, and the thousands is a decimal, does nothing -- the numbers stay the same.

So, to fix this, I have a macro that uses each cell as a string, then removes the spaces and such (note: using find/replace on `" "` doesn't work on its own).  It works great when the numbers have no decimals.  However, when it hits a number with a decimal, it doesn't include it.

Here's my code:

```
Sub format_Worksheet()
Dim cel as Range, rng as Range
Set rng = ("A1:A10")

For each cel in rng
     cel.value = Change_Weight_to_Proper_Numbers(cel.value)
next cel

End Sub
```

and the function:

```
Private Function Change_Weight_to_Proper_Numbers(val As String)
Dim cel As Range
Dim str$, slice$
Dim i&, k&

For i = 1 To Len(val)
    slice = Mid(val, i, 1)
    Debug.Print slice
    If slice <> " " And slice <> "," And slice <> "." Then
        k = k & slice
    End If
    If slice = "," Or slice = "." Then
        k = k & "."  '  HERE! This line DOES run, but there's no decimal added to the string??
    End If
    Debug.Print "So far you have: " & k
Next i

Debug.Print Trim(k)

Change_Weight_to_Proper_Numbers = Trim(k)

End Function
```

Again, this works fine when the number is, say, `1 293 999`, but doesn't when it's `1 293 99.90`.  It ignores the `.` altogether in my loop.  The line that adds the decimal runs, but the decimal doesn't get added to the string??

Guesses as to what's happening: I think it's something to do with the `String` being viewed as an `integer` or something? (that's not right, but I don't know how to say it)...I thought a string could take any character, hence my use of `String`.  Should I instead change this to be a `Long` or `Double`?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but does [Text to Columns](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Split-names-by-using-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-2cd989db-2b1f-4d89-b17b-534250ff9905) not help?

Comment: @loannis - I've tried that too. I'll update my OP with my full procedure, to prevent any [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) issues.

Comment: How about `Replace(Replace(Selection, " ", ""), ",", ".") * -1 * -1`?

Comment: What type of file is this Excel sheet?  If it is truly Excel (e.g. xls, xls?) the values, if numeric, should just convert to using the separators on your machine.  However, if those values are text, then some will convert and some won't, leaving you with a mess.  If the sheet is a .csv file, then you need to import the file, and use the text import wizard to convert the numbers before Excel has a chance to munge things up.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - it's .xlsx.

Comment: Then at least some of the values are probably text. After running the conversion macro, I would check to be sure that the new values are what you require. Some may have  been converted improperly from your perspective, if Excel initially saw them as a number.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - will do, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `k` variable is not a string, so you will never be able to concatenate a decimal character to it. It is a Long.

Here's a squib I put together for you to convert the numbers. I just hard coded the ranges for the example of what to do with the strings. You can use whatever technique you like for the real ranges.

```
Public Sub ConvertNumbers2US()
    Dim i&, s$, v
    v = [a1:a12]
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        s = v(i, 1)
        s = Replace(s, Chr$(160), "")
        s = Replace(s, " ", "")
        s = Replace(s, ".", "")
        s = Replace(s, ",", ".")
        v(i, 1) = Val(s)
    Next
    [b1:b12] = v
End Sub
```

Comment: "Your `k` variable is not a string...` - Ahaha, D'oh! I don't know how I missed that...time to break out my [rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).  Thanks for the sub too, I'll check that out and see if it works.  Why use an array though?  Couldn't you just do `for i = 1 to ubound(v) // s = Cells(i,1)`?  Also, `val()` is pretty neat, haven't seen that before!  (Also, why does `?Ubound([a1:a12])` give a type mismatch error in the Immediate Window?

Comment: I always try to minimize the number of times I ask VBA to pierce the boundary between VBA and Excel. Doing so is expensive... as in it is not efficient. So getting all of the cell values with one call to an array is cheap. I process each array element entirely on the VBA side. When done, write them all back to the worksheet in one go. Again, cheap. Two total calls across the boundary instead of two calls for every cell!

Comment: Ahhh, great explanation - thanks! I'll have to start trying to do that as well...

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ",""))
```

Substitute spaces and commas with nothing then convert to a value `1 293 99.90` returned as `129399.9` for me:

```
18890           18890
18 644          18644
19 264          19264
19 318.02       19318.02
19 113,6        191136
7 407,75        740775
17 988,75       1798875
14 456          14456
19.168          19.168
18 922          18922
19 504,5        195045
18 310,29375    1831029375
1 293 99.90     129399.9
```

Comment: Not quite - the decimals in the list are correct, but the commas should also be decimals.

Comment: Change the first empty double quotes to have a full stop in

Answer (score 0):

try =(field)+0 in the raw file

Comment: Tried - if `14 456` is in A1, putting this in B1, `=14  456+0` won't work, I get the error that the formula I typed contains an error.  Thanks though.